# Take the first three (or desired amount) from int array, store those into a new temporarily array while removing those 3 in the OG array.

Tags: c

So technically I'm actually trying to design something else but in doing so I'm I have to figure out a possible way to do this. I can handle all the more complicated stuff later on, but allow me to elaborate on what I need: 
Say I have an int array, say: 
 `int listofNums[]` and the contents is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107` I want pass sections of these into multiple threads, so say thread 1 will get array `[1,2,3]` and thread 2 will get `[4,5,6]` .....so on. I can do the thread part, but I just want to know if their are any function or methods which I can call with could grab the first 3 in each iteration while remove those 3 from the original.

Comment: If this is being set as a C programming problem, it seems likely that you are expected to directly manipulate the data at a low level. The good news is that there __is__ a function to move 3 items from one array to another. The bad news is, you haven't written it yet.

Answer (score 0):

do you need the initial listofNums to REMOVE the three that each thread is getting, or just not point to them anymore?  If you remove them you have to create a new array, copy the new array, then destroy/free the old one.  There is no dynamic array resizing in C.

A better way is to just have each thread increment the array pointer, and wrap this logic in a mutex of course.  Here is a sudo code example of what i mean:

```
int main(){

 int listofNums[SIZE] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,100,101,102, 111, 112, 113};
 int * first_element = &listofNums[0];
 p_thread_create(Thread_1_entry_function, listofNums,0,0,etc);
 p_thread_create(Thread_2_entry_function, listofNums,0,0,etc);
 p_thread_create(Thread_3_entry_function, listofNums,0,0,etc);
 p_thread_create(Thread_4_entry_function, listofNums,0,0,etc);

 //listofNums should now be pointing to the listofNums[12], should not be used unless you re assign it to listofNums[0] explcitly.
 listofNums = first_element; //array decay has happened, sizeof listofNums should be sizeof int instead of sizeof int * SIZE (num of array elements).

 p_thread_join(all_threads);
}

void Thread_1_entry_function(void* listofNums, void* arg2, etc){
  mutex_acquire(Some_mutex);
  int Thread_1_listofNums[3] = {*listofNums++, *listofNums++, *listofNums++};
  mutex_release(Some_mutex);  
  //other thread stuff that uses Thread_1_listofNums.  listofNums is now pointing to the index [3] instead of [0] for the next thread.

}

void Thread_2_entry_function(void* listofNums, void* arg2, etc){
  mutex_acquire(Some_mutex);
  int Thread_2_listofNums[3] = {*listofNums++, *listofNums++, *listofNums++};
  mutex_release(Some_mutex);  
  //other thread stuff that uses Thread_2_listofNums.  listofNums is now pointing to the index [6] instead of [0] for the next thread.

}

void Thread_3_entry_function(void* listofNums, void* arg2, etc){
  mutex_acquire(Some_mutex);
  int Thread_3_listofNums[3] = {*listofNums++, *listofNums++, *listofNums++};
  mutex_release(Some_mutex);  
  //other thread stuff that uses Thread_3_listofNums.  listofNums is now pointing to the index [9] instead of [0] for the next thread.

}

void Thread_4_entry_function(void* listofNums, void* arg2, etc){
  mutex_acquire(Some_mutex);
  int Thread_4_listofNums[3] = {*listofNums++, *listofNums++, *listofNums++};
  mutex_release(Some_mutex);  
  //other thread stuff that uses Thread_4_listofNums.  listofNums is now pointing to the index [12] instead of [0] for the next thread.

}
```